# c# dealing with data types in a multi rdbms application

Tags: c#, rdbms

I finally managed to get my application to interact with some RDBMS (SQLite, MySQL, Oracle and theoretically SQL Server). I'm already capable of read/write data from the dbms.

Now I'm writing an interface to let the user to create/delete tables on such database, but I'm stuck on how to display the column data type available:
listing the 'TypeName' from `conn.GetSchema("DataTypes")` will give me a different (and rather verbose) list of types with no direct counterparts in CLR (no easy cast stuff), but esthetically appropriate to the selected DBMS.

I rather show a list of standard CLR types because these would be both easy to manage and sterile as for the visual impact.

How would you deal with such issue?

Comment: I'd have a look at how the enumeration SqlDbType works.

Comment: ok, thank you for your anwser.  i guess that's the best way for a generic approach to dbms handling. I'll have to use parametrized queries rather than plain strings but that's for better. Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: while we're at it, do you know of any book(s) explaining the .net framework (NOT the programming stuff, only the purpose of each class or wathever)?

Comment: There are several framework books. I've never seen one that goes through each class though, it would be a hefty tome. My rule of thumb is, it's in there somewhere.

Comment: And i highly appreciate that! if it wasn't for StackOverflow community posts, i would pass a good deal of my coding time ramming my head on the keyboard :) (hope i write it correctly!). Thanks for your help, anyway.